# laravel 8 jetstream inertia add new menu item shows white site

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

I added into a test project a new menu item into **AppLayout.vue**.

```
<div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
    <jet-nav-link :href="route('dashboard')" :active="route().current('dashboard')">
        Dashboard
    </jet-nav-link>
    <jet-nav-link :href="route('vehicles')" :active="route().current('vehicles')">
        Vehicles
    </jet-nav-link>
</div>
```

Into the routes into **web.php** I added this:

```
Route::resource('vehicles', VehiclesController::class);
```

After run-in rpm run dev, I see only a white page and this error message into the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Ziggy error: route 'vehicles' is not in the route list.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution.

```
<jet-nav-link :href="route('vehicles.index')" :active="route().current('vehicles')">
    Vehicles
</jet-nav-link>
```